# Why isn't this little snip working?

Tags: php

I've completely lost my sense of this little snippet. What am I doing wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['QuestionAsked'])) str_replace('?','',$_POST['QuestionAsked']);
```

I've checked the post array and it is in there. I'm just truing to remove the ? 
Why is my string replace not working?

TIA

Comment: You are discarding the return value, which contains the result of the replace.

Comment: I don't understand, Jon.

Comment: `str_replace()` does not modify the value, but returns the new, changed one.

Comment: Look at the [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and see what you are doing differently. Assume the `if` is not there.

Comment: Typical confusion of a language/framework that alternates between _in-place altering functions_ and _return-based renewal functions_ willy-nilly.

Comment: All you are doing is evaluating the result of str_replace, instead you should capture the return value and store it in a new variable or overwrite the post variable.

Comment: This is usually solved just by looking at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), there's no indication of a reference variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$ans="";
if(isset($_POST['QuestionAsked'])) 
    $ans=str_replace('?','',$_POST['QuestionAsked']);
```

$ans should have what you want.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen,
I'll toy around with $ans

Comment: Yup, you un-broke my brain. Thanks jh314.